# H2O Autoencoder Serialized to MOJO format cannot be loaded by H2O library

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, h2o, autoencoder

My dependencies:

- python3.7
- h2o==3.24.0.5

I serialized trained H2O autoencoder to Mojo format by means of:

```
autoencoder_model.download_mojo(path = './custom_path')
```

to use it later in another place for some sort of novelty detection.

Then I try to load this serialized model by the following methods:

```
model = h2o.upload_mojo('./custom_path/DeepLearning_model_python_1575291468476_40.zip')
```

It fails with:

```
generic Model Build progress: |▏ (failed)                                                 

    |   0%
*** OSError: Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_9fccdffd1c011bdec61e5733e58f47e7 failed with an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Primitive.
stacktrace: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Primitive.
        at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonPrimitive(JsonElement.java:122)
        at hex.genmodel.descriptor.JsonModelDescriptorReader.extractTableFromJson(JsonModelDescriptorReader.java:71)
        at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readModelDescriptor(ModelMojoReader.java:194)
        at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readAll(ModelMojoReader.java:186)
        at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readFrom(ModelMojoReader.java:59)
        at hex.generic.Generic$MojoDelegatingModelDriver.computeImpl(Generic.java:64)
        at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:222)
        at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1425)
        at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Then I try another method from the documentation:

```
model = h2o.import_mojo('./custom_path/DeepLearning_model_python_1575291468476_40.zip')
```

It fails with the same exception:

```
generic Model Build progress: |▏ (failed)                                                     |   0%
*** OSError: Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_8640c4218f00c561935274c25fe5429f failed with an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Primitive.
stacktrace: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Primitive.
        at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonPrimitive(JsonElement.java:122)
        at hex.genmodel.descriptor.JsonModelDescriptorReader.extractTableFromJson(JsonModelDescriptorReader.java:71)
        at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readModelDescriptor(ModelMojoReader.java:194)
        at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readAll(ModelMojoReader.java:186)
        at hex.genmodel.ModelMojoReader.readFrom(ModelMojoReader.java:59)
        at hex.generic.Generic$MojoDelegatingModelDriver.computeImpl(Generic.java:64)
        at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:222)
        at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1425)
        at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

One mode method:

```
h2o.load_model('./custom_path/DeepLearning_model_python_1575291468476_40.zip')
```

Fails with:

```
*** h2o.exceptions.H2OResponseError: Server error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Error: Missing magic number 0x1CED at stream start
  Request: POST /99/Models.bin/
```

So none of these methods work, then I try another method which always works well for me:

```
h2o.mojo_predict_pandas(data_to_reconstruct, mojo_zip_path='./custom_path/DeepLearning_model_python_1575291468476_40.zip')
```

and it works but it returns reconstruction error values per every column and adds 'reconstr_' prefix at the beginning of every column name, not common reconstruction error as it's done by autoencoder_model.anomaly() method which returns frame with Reconstruction.MSE column.
The order of those values is different from what is presented in "Reconstruction.MSE".

**How can I compute the same reconstruction error as it's done by model.anomaly() or can I fix the problem with loading of the serialized model by one of the methods?**

Comment: What you've reached is a bug in H2O. Internally, H2O has a check to only allow supported MOJOs (https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/dcc90387c61a33e1e8efecc2a0908d1e041a82dd/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/generic/Generic.java#L24). And DL MOJOs are not supported.

However, the check is placed incorrectly, after the whole MOJO is parsed. Therefore, you see parsing failure first and not a tidy "error" message.

I've created two JIRAs to track this problem: 
https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7166 (Improvement to the checks done)
https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7167

Comment: @PavelPscheidl thank you for the urgent answer, I'll keep my eye on the status. I wonder if I can use the same error function to compute the "general" reconstruction error from what I have after the application of mojo_predict_pandas method. I have "reconstr_<original_column_name>" errors per every input column.

Comment: @PavelPscheidl One more point, the zip file I have for DNN model after serialization to Mojo is actually a textual file with parameters of neural network I trained.

Comment: I had a look at the issue and saw you're using version 3.24.0.5. Please update to the latest version if possible and the JSON issue is resolved there. However, MOJO scoring for DL will not be possible using MOJO import, as this is blocked by other issue currently undergoing development.

Comment: The JIRA relevant to you is now only https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7167.